# Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-storage

i am trying to display and image on a chat web app i am making. the file (image) is being uploaded to firebase storage but its not displaying. the function to display message is working well with regular text
but for some reason the image isn't. when it's done uploading i can get the downloadUrl but its not displaying. i have three files `messageForm`, `FileModal`.

here is the code for FileModal :

```
    addFile = event => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
        this.setState({ file });
    }
}

sendFile = () => {
    const { file } = this.state;
    const { uploadFile, closeModal } = this.props;

    if (file !== null) {
        if (this.isAuthorized(file.name)) {
            const metadata = { contentType: mime.lookup(file.name) };
            uploadFile(file, metadata);
            closeModal();
            this.clearFile();
        }
    }
}

isAuthorized = filename => this.state.authorized.includes(mime.lookup(filename));

clearFile = () => this.setState({ file: null })
render() {
    const { modal, closeModal } = this.props;
    return (
        <Modal basic open={modal} onClose={closeModal}>
            <Modal.Header>Select an image file</Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Content>
                <Input
                    fluid
                    label="file Types: JPG, PNG"
                    onChange={this.addFile}
                    name="file"
                    type="file"
                />
            </Modal.Content>
            <Modal.Actions>
                <Button
                    color="green"
                    inverted
                    onClick={this.sendFile}
                >
                    <Icon name={"checkmark"} /> Send
                </Button>
                <Button
                    color="red"
                    inverted
                    onClick={closeModal}
                >
                    <Icon name={"remove"} /> Cancel
                </Button>
            </Modal.Actions>
        </Modal>
    );
}}
```

here's the code for messageForm

```
uploadFile = (file, metadata) => {
const pathToUpload = this.state.channel.id;
const ref = this.props.messagesRef;
const filePath = `chat/public/${file.name}`;

this.setState({
  uploadState: 'uploading',
  uploadTask: this.state.storageRef.child(filePath).put(file, metadata)
},
  () =>{
    // progesss function
    this.state.uploadTask.on('state_changed', snap => {
      const percentUploaded = Math.round((snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100)
      this.setState({ percentUploaded })
    },
      err => {
        //error function
        console.error(err);
        this.setState({
          errors: this.state.errors.concat(err),
          uploadState: 'error',
          uploadTask: null
        })
      },
      () => {
        // on complete upload function, that is waht to do when it has upload to the database  
        this.state.uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadUrl => {
          console.log(downloadUrl);
          this.sendFileMessage(downloadUrl, ref, filePath)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
          this.setState({
            errors: this.state.errors.concat(err),
            uploadState: 'error',
            uploadTask: null
          })
        })
      }
    )
}
)
}

sendFileMessage = (fileUrl, ref, pathToUpload) => {
ref
  .child(pathToUpload)
  .push()
  .set(this.createMessage(fileUrl))
  .then(() => {
    this.setState({ uploadState: "done" });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    this.setState({
      errors: this.state.errors.concat(err)
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error mentioned, your path values **cannot** be an empty string or can't contain values such as `“.”, “#”, “$”, “[”, or “]”`. I would suggest that you double check the value of these variables and make sure that they are valid paths:

- pathToUpload
- filePath